# Chrome webdriver send keys does not send '3'

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver

For some reason, I am unable to write character '3' into the input element on the page.

This code:

```
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--dns-prefetch-disable')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-proxy-server')
    chromeDriverPath = self.getChromeDriverPath()
    os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromeDriverPath
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromeDriverPath, chrome_options=chrome_options)

    self.driver.get(self.loginUrl)
    login = self.driver.find_element_by_id('login_credit')
    login.send_keys("12345")
```

results in "1245" being written in the login input...
Can someone help please?
I use python 2.7, the latest chrome and the latest chromedriver

EDIT:

```
login.send_keys("3")

login.send_keys("\3")
```

don't work either.

```
login.send_keys("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!@#$%^&*()")
```

- only the "3" was missing in the string...

what worked was

```
login.send_keys(Keys.NUMPAD3)
```

as Andersson suggested below, but this is not a solution.

I tried it in the google search box and I experienced the same behaviour.

Comment: Try `login.send_keys("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")`

Comment: Nope, the ‘3’ is still not printed even when i write it completely alone

Comment: How about `from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys` `login.send_keys(Keys.NUMPAD3)`?

Comment: change your script to open a public website like google and send keys 12345 to input box,  if  3 still missing,  the problem most possible from  chrome and chromedriver.  Then try other version chrome or chromedriver.

Comment: wow, the Keys.NUMPAD3 actually worked :D. But I wont accept it as an answer - I don't want to parse strings and send it char by char, if you know what I mean. The problem occurs in all input boxes I tried (google etc.)

Comment: I had the same problem with other characters and was able to find a solution here :https://stackoverflow.com/a/54802193/9188586

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Updating to latest [chrome driver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) resolved this issue.

Comment: It is a bug in a previous version of the software. It's an entirely reasonable answer to say they should update to the latest version of the software.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using **`send_keys("12345")`** you can use any of the alternatives mentioned below :

1. Use **`Keys.NUMPAD3`** :

   ```
   login.send_keys(Keys.NUMPAD3)
   ```
2. Use `JavascriptExecutor` with **`getElementById`** :

   ```
   self.driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('login_credit').value='12345'")
   ```
3. Use `JavascriptExecutor` with **`getElementsById`** :

   ```
   self.driver.execute_script("document.getElementsById('login_credit')[0].value='12345'")
   ```

Comment: it should be `document.getElementById('login_credit').value='12345'` or `document.getElementsById('login_credit')[0].value='12345'` and yes, this works too, thanks! :D kinda ugly solution though

Answer (score 0):

Strange issue, Try to pass string variable in `send_keys` and try may be it works for you

```
my_str = "12345"
login = self.driver.find_element_by_id('login_credit')
login.send_keys(my_str)
```

Comment: you surely meant `login.send_keys(my_str) :) Of course I use variable here, the "12345" was just an example