# FitNesse: How to send '@' to Internet Explorer

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I encountered the following problem during testing with FitNesse using the `hsac-fitnesse-fixtures`:

I try to send an email address to a field on a webpage.

However, instead of the `'@'`, the `'é'` is filled in.

In other browsers (`Chrome`, `Firefox`) I haven't encountered this issue.

SOLUTION: change keyboard settings to the US

Comment: Very strange indeed. What are the characters before and after the `@`?

Comment: What keyboard layout are you using in Windows? I think this might be related to https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4523. I believe this is more of an 'Issue' to create on GitHub and not a stackoverflow question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send keys not working selenium webdriver python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46770697/send-keys-not-working-selenium-webdriver-python/46773859#46773859)

Comment: Check this as well- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47248275/chrome-webdriver-send-keys-does-not-send-3/47263704#47263704

Comment: @FriedHoeben it's just a regular email adress used to log in to a webportal
Changing to US keyboard fixed the issue :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you already found out: it is a selenium windows issue. Switch to US keyboard layout as workaround.