# SendKeys() method ignores some characters when sending to a text box

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I move my Selenium installation to a new server, since then some tests using logins no longer work.

After investigation, I found that the password field was populated with an incorrect value. Therefore the tests failed.

I'm trying to do the following :

```
_passWordTextBox.Clear();
_passWordTextBox.SendKeys("!!ä{dasd$352310!!!\\_XY>èà$£<?^^");
```

Here is how the field is populated after those lines:

[image]

The "!" character was the only one missing. It worked on the previous server. Some other suspicious characters (like $ éà<) also worked.

I've looked at locale settings (culture differences) between the servers.

**From these characters sent in a Password string**:

```
  !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

All of these worked correctly:

```
"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\  _ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}
```

Only these failed to be sent correctly:

```
!]^`~
```

I've also tried in other fields (such as a Description field) and see the same failure.

I've tried to see if the command was sent correctly to the selenium server, but the logs seem to suggest it worked:

```
08:05:35.850 DEBUG [ReverseProxyHandler.execute] - To upstream: {"value":["!\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~?"]}
```

It means that the server receives the command correctly, but for some reason the driver or the server doesn't execute properly.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Comment: Try sending one character at a time... now does it work? Also your double backslash is treated as an escape, `\\` -> `\`.

Comment: Sending one character at a time doesn't solve it

Comment: What OS are you on? It is the Keyboard driver that makes the difference. On Windows, control center has keyboard settings - check whether it is the same on both the machines.

Comment: I don't think the keyboard drivers are different, since i've been able to type the !]^`~ myself with the keyboard, it's only the sendKeys() that doesn't send them
As for OS , i'm on Windows 10 both machines, with keyboard Swiss French on both machines aswell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into multiple system settings i discovered that both my piloting and executing machine add the same regional settings **(Format : French(Switzerland) , Keyboard : French(Switzerland)**, and I didn't look any further.
While fiddling around i discovered this setting : 
[image: Windows Setting for non Unicode programs]

As it turns out , the Language for non-Unicode programs was set to French(Switzerland) on the machine executing the tests. Changing it to English(UK) resolved the problem.

Probably a bug in chromedriver.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
_passWordTextBox.SendKeys(@"!!ä{dasd$352310!!!\\_XY>èà$£<?^^");
```

Maybe is for the validates from field.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using clipboard:

```
public static void SendValueFromClipboard(this IWebElement txtField, string value)
        {
            Clipboard.SetText(value);
            txtField.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control + "v");
        }
```

This is written on C#, you will need to rewrite it in language, you are using.

Comment: Using the clipboard is not an option as the machine piloting the tests and the one executing them are not the same, and thus don't share a clipboard.

Answer (score -1):

Your solution doesn't work for me, since I already have that setting set to English, but here's a solution I found if anyone else's interested.

Just change your keyboard to ENG UK in task bar.